# How to run jQuery before loading page or how can call back "getJson(function(data))"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a chart that can be filtered by selecting the date with the data I got from the JSON file.
I get default data for chart from JSON file before date filtering.I have output in the log, but I can't display it (default data) in the chart.
I noticed that it was caused by running chart before entering the `getJson(function(data){})` function. How can I fix it ?

```js
$.getJSON('LS22731.json', function(data)

  { /* POWER ON TIME*/
    data.forEach(function(item) {

      data_power = item['PowerOnTime'];
      dtarr.push(data_power);

      label = item.CratedAt;
      lbarr.push(label);
    });

    var len = dtarr.length;
    var lastvalue = new Date(dtarr[len - 1]);

    var PowerOnTime = moment(lastvalue).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm');
    OnTime = moment(PowerOnTime).format('h:mm:ss');
    document.getElementById("pot").innerHTML = OnTime;
    dateTime = lastvalue.toDateString();
    document.getElementById("pod").innerHTML = dateTime;


    /* ******************************************************************************* */
    /* GET DATA FROM JSON */
    var len = data.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

      datatime = data[i]['CratedAt'];
      data_time.push(datatime);

      dataenergy = data[i]['Energy (J)'];
      data_energy.push(dataenergy);

      datavolt1 = data[i]['V1 (Volts)'];
      akim1 = Math.abs(data[i]['I1 (Ampers)']);
      power1 = datavolt1 * akim1 * 1000;
      data_phase1.push(power1);

      datavolt2 = data[i]['V2 (Volts)'];
      akim2 = Math.abs(data[i]['I2 (Ampers)']);
      power2 = datavolt2 * akim2 * 1000;
      data_phase2.push(power2);

      datavolt3 = data[i]['V3 (Volts)'];
      akim3 = Math.abs(data[i]['I3 (Ampers)']);
      power3 = datavolt3 * akim3 * 1000;
      data_phase3.push(power3);

    }
    /* ******************************************************** */
    /*CHANGE DATA FORMAT */

    var last_time = data_time[len - 1];
    /*console.log(lastvalue);*/
    var y_date = new Date(last_time);
    var y_date_label = y_date.setHours(y_date.getHours() - 1);
    var datelabel = new Date(y_date_label);
    var start_time = moment(datelabel).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm');

    data_time.forEach(function(item) {
      form = moment(item).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm');
      date_label.push(form);
    });

    console.log(date_label);

    var startindex = date_label.indexOf(start_time);
    var lastindex = date_label.indexOf(last_time);

    date_arr = date_label.slice(startindex, lastindex);
    data_arr = data_energy.slice(startindex, lastindex);


    phase_1 = data_phase1.slice(startindex, lastindex);
    phase_2 = data_phase2.slice(startindex, lastindex);
    phase_3 = data_phase3.slice(startindex, lastindex);

    console.log(date_arr);

    date_arr.forEach(function(item) {
      label = moment(item).format("DD/MM, h:mm");
      chart_label.push(label);
    });

    console.log(chart_label);


  });

         ....
         ...
         ....
        <div class="col-6 col-m-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card-large">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <center>
                        <div class="container" style="width:500px; height:500px;">
                            <input type="datetime-local" id="start" name="startdate">
                            <input type="datetime-local" id="end" name="lastdate">
                            <button onclick="changeData();">Search </button>
                            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-m-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card-large"> 
                <div class="card-header">
                    <center>
                        <div class="container" style="width:550px; height:200px;">
                            <input type="datetime-local" id="start_power" name="startdate">
                            <input type="datetime-local" id="end_power" name="lastdate">
                            <button onclick="change_DataPower();">Search </button>
                            <canvas id="my_Chart"></canvas> 
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        ....
       .....
      ......


<script>

const changeData = () => {
  var get_start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var get_end = document.getElementById("end").value;

  var startDate = moment(get_start).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm');
  console.log(startDate);

  var endDate = moment(get_end).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm');
  console.log(endDate);

  var startindex = date_label.indexOf(startDate);
  console.log(startindex);

  var lastindex = date_label.indexOf(endDate);
  console.log(lastindex);

  var datearr = date_label.slice(startindex, lastindex);
  console.log(datearr);

  var dataarr = data_energy.slice(startindex, lastindex);
  console.log(dataarr);

  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = dataarr;
  myChart.data.labels = datearr;
  myChart.update();

};
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
console.log("payar");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: chart_label,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(129, 198, 2228)',
      borderColor: '#959DA6',
      data: data_energy,
      label: 'Energy (J)',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#959DA6'
      }

    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "1 Saatlik Enerji Tüketimi",
      fontColor: "#959DA6",
    },
    responsive: 'true',
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "#959DA6"
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "#959DA6",
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 6,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the button disabled and only enable it after receiving the data.

```
<button id="search" onclick="changeData();" disabled>Search </button>
```

and

```
$('#search').prop('disabled', false);
```

at the end of your `$.getJSON()` callback;